# How to get size of resized image?

Tags: c#, image, uwp, bitmap, image-size

In UWP I have this Image

```
<Image Source="{Binding Bitmap}" Stretch="Uniform"/>
```

I want to get size of the resized Bitmap *inside* Image element in code behind, so I have this

```
Image img = ...;

var width = img.Width; // this gives size of Image element not the bitmap resized
                       // inside the Image.
```

So the original Bitmap could have size of 1920x1080 but Image element size is 300x200, so the bitmap inside it would have size of 300x112.5 given `Stretch=Uniform`. I want to get 300x112.5

Comment: In wpf you could use the ActualWidth property of the image element , not sure if uwp has a similar property.

Comment: @fstam thanks a lot. if you give this as answer, i will accept. It's working!

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary, UWP also has [ActualWidth](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.actualwidth#Windows_UI_Xaml_FrameworkElement_ActualWidth). `DecodePixelWidth` for the BitmapImage source should be the [same value](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.image#image-files-and-performance) as the `Width` or `ActualWidth` of the Image control that displays that source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the ActualWidth/ActualHeight properties.